# summing rows in groups in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe:

```
  ID        Name     L    Prob
  044FB2AE  X        L0   1.0
  044FB2AE  X        L1   0.4
  044FB2AE  X        L1   0.3
  044FB2AE  X        L2   0.6 
  044FB2AE  X        L2   0.3
  044F3333  Y        L0   0.1
  044F3333  Y        L0   0.4
  044F3333  Y        L1   0.3
  044F3333  Y        L2   0.6 
  044F3333  Y        L2   0.4
```

I want to return a dataframe that calculates the sum of the probabilities of every Name in each level L.

So for the above the result should be a dataframe like this:

```
  ID        Name     L    Prob
  044FB2AE  X        L0   1.0
  044FB2AE  X        L1   0.7
  044FB2AE  X        L2   0.9
  044F3333  Y        L0   0.5
  044F3333  Y        L1   0.3
  044F3333  Y        L2   1.0
```

I know I need to group them based on Name and L,

```
df.groupby(['Name','L'])
```

But then how do I sum what's inside each grouping?

Answer (score 1):

It seems you need [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and [`GroupBy.sum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.sum.html):

```
df = df.groupby(['ID','Name','L'], as_index=False, sort=False).Prob.sum()
print (df)
         ID Name   L  Prob
0  044FB2AE    X  L0   1.0
1  044FB2AE    X  L1   0.7
2  044FB2AE    X  L2   0.9
3  044F3333    Y  L0   0.5
4  044F3333    Y  L1   0.3
5  044F3333    Y  L2   1.0
```

---

```
df = df.groupby(['Name','L'], as_index=False, sort=False).Prob.sum()
print (df)
  Name   L  Prob
0    X  L0   1.0
1    X  L1   0.7
2    X  L2   0.9
3    Y  L0   0.5
4    Y  L1   0.3
5    Y  L2   1.0
```